# zkcm-library not finding the mpfr-library

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, static-linking, mpfr, zkcm

I just installed the [zkcm library](http://sourceforge.net/p/zkcm/home/Home/) on my kubuntu machine and I'm having trouble compiling c++ code.

I have installed the `gmp` and `mpfr` libraries and checked that they work; the code

```
mpfr_t m1, m2, m3; 
mpfr_init(m1); mpfr_init(m2); mpfr_init(m3); 
mpfr_mul(m1, m2, m3, MPFR_RNDN);
```

compiles and runs.

I then try to use `zkcm`; I try compliling the line

```
zkcm_matrix m;
```

and get a bunch of errors seemingly about `zkcm` not finding `mpfr`; here is the beginning of the output:

```
/usr/local/lib/libzkcm.a(zkcm_c.o): In function `zkcm_init_ri(zkcm*, double, double)':
/home/jorgen/Downloads/zkcm_lib-0.4.0/srcs/zkcm_c.c:126: undefined reference to `mpfr_inits'
/home/jorgen/Downloads/zkcm_lib-0.4.0/srcs/zkcm_c.c:127: undefined reference to `mpfr_set_d'
/usr/local/lib/libzkcm.a(zkcm_c.o): In function `zkcm_init_ri_str(zkcm*, char const*, char const*)':
/home/jorgen/Downloads/zkcm_lib-0.4.0/srcs/zkcm_c.c:132: undefined reference to `mpfr_inits'
/home/jorgen/Downloads/zkcm_lib-0.4.0/srcs/zkcm_c.c:136: undefined reference to `mpfr_set_str'
/home/jorgen/Downloads/zkcm_lib-0.4.0/srcs/zkcm_c.c:134: undefined reference to `mpfr_set_ui'
```

I have tried to follow the instructions infrom `zkcm`; I have the lines

```
#include "mpfr.h"
#include "zkcm.hpp"
```

and I compile the code (called `test.cpp`) using

```
g++ test.cpp -msse2 -std=c++11 -O2 -lm -lmpfr -lgmp -lgmpxx -lzkcm -o test
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried changing the order you pass the library names to the compiler?

Comment: I tried it a bit now, with no results.. Any particular order in mind? I'd rather not try all 120:). The order in the OP is the one from the zkcm README.

Comment: I've seen things fail to link if the dependent libraries of one library were put in the wrong order relative to the library itself (so, just two orders to test). But it seems not to be the case this time.

Comment: If zkcm uses MPFR, then perhaps `-lzkcm` should be put before `-lmpfr`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The library order is incorrect: according to the error message, zkcm uses MPFR, so that `-lzkcm` should be put before `-lmpfr` (which itself should be put before `-lgmp` because MPFR uses GMP).

Otherwise the following happens: If the linker founds a MPFR symbol that is not used by `test.cpp` (or some dependency), it will drop it. And if such a symbol is used by zkcm, this will yield an error since `-lzkcm` comes later in the command line. This also explains why you may get errors for some MPFR symbols and not others (and errors may appear and disappear when the `test.cpp` code and the zkcm code change).

This should be sufficient to solve the problem here. But look at [this answer to "Linker order - GCC"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/409470/3782797) for more general rules (this answer also deals with cyclic dependencies).

Comment: It works, thanks a lot! For some reason I was thinking the order logic was opposite.